# React BrowserRouter <Link> doesn't load the component which accepts "/' exact Route - Path defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, url-routing

My Navigation component code

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";
<Router>
        <header>
          <ul className="social">
            {/* Couldn't figure this out */}
            {/* Link doesn't route properly but a href does */}
            <li>
              <Link to="/"> 
              !Home
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
</header>
</Router>
```

Tag works for loading the webpage but  tag doesnt work.

The class where I have defined my HashRouter and Switch.
When invoking " !Home " it doesn't load and nor outputs anything in the chrome/firefox console but this same link in href "Home" works and loads the page.

```
<HashRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              render={props => <Posts postsObj={this.state.blog} />}
            />
            <Route
              path="/post1"
              render={props => <Post postObj={this.state.blog[0]} />}
            />
            <Route
              path="/post2"
              render={props => <Post postObj={this.state.blog[1]} />}
            />
            <Route
              path="/post3"
              render={props => <Post postObj={this.state.blog[2]} />}
            />
          </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
```

Calling "Main.jsx" from "MainApp.jsx"

```
<div>
        <Header />
        <section>
          <Main /> // Calling function here.
          <Nav />
        </section>
        <Social />
        <Footer />
      </div>
```

Github Source code : https://github.com/SensehacK/react-app

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two parallel `Router`s (`HashRouter` is a special kind of `Router` component) in your project, one in the `Header` component and another in `Main`. Having multiple routers is confusing and could easily break routing, which is probably why your `Link` is not working as expected.

Since the `HashRouter` seems to be the one that's expected to work, you might want to move it to the top level, for example to the `MainApp` component and remove the other. Make sure whenever you use `Link`, it is nested in a `Router` (or `HashRouter` in your case) through its parents/ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I got confused between HashRouter and BrowserRouter.

I followed HashRouter in the main component and use

```
<Main Component> 
<HashRouter> <Switch> 
<Route  exact path="/" render= {component_name1} />
 </Switch>  </HashRouter>
</Main Component>
```

And when I was trying to link the path "/" in different component towards "component_name1"
I was using `<Link to="/" > Go Home </Link>` ( BrowserRouter ) in my HashRouter routing definition.

So for HashRouter to work I need to use `<NavLink to="/">Go Home</NavLink>`
I was following 2 different sources and hastily forgot about differences of HashRouter and BrowserRouter by even their names and implementation. 
Sometimes deadlines takes the best of you to even spot the basic stuff.

Thanks for the response though @Claire Lin

[Github code fix commit](https://github.com/SensehacK/react-app/commit/7ede2731a574478b795191cf7e9c9e9091fbf378)